# question about .load jQuery function

Tags: django, jquery

I am using the.load function and I am having some trouble:

```
<form id="register_frm" method="post" action = "/login/register/"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New User:</legend> 
        <div>
        <label for="id_email">Email</label>
        <input id="id_email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" /> 
        </div>      
        <div> 
        <label for="id_conf_email">Confirm Email</label> 
        <input id="id_conf_email" type="text" name="conf_email" maxlength="30" /> 
        </div> 
    </fieldset> 
<input name = "register" type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
```

I am trying to write a .load script that would display a success method if the 2 email address match.

```
function register_js() {
    $('#register_frm').load('/register/confirm');
    return false;
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    ('#register_frm').submit(register_js);
    });
```

1. How to change the code so the `.load` would submit a `post` request instead of the `get`?
2. When I override the register button, how to make the `.load` submit the email and conf_email field so that I can verify them on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `load` you want to use `post`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#register_frm').submit(function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        // if you want to get the url from the action use
        // var url = $form.attr('action');
        var url = '/register/confirm';
        $.post( url, $form.serialize(), function(html) {
            $form(html);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note if you don't reuse the `$form` variable as noted in the comments, you can simply use `$(this).serialize()` in the parameters to `post`.

Comment: I am using a .load function because I am returning a "success message" that should be displayed instead of the `register_frm` section of the webpage. Is this possible withe $.post?

Comment: @Rami - yes, post can receive html, json, etc.  You just need to specify the type if it's not html.  If it is, just use the `html` method on the jQuery object for the form to replace it's contents or use `replaceWith` to replace the form entirely (probably better, but not shown in my updated example).

Comment: @Rami - FWIW, both `load` and `post` are simply convenience functions for the `ajax` method.  `load` is essentially an `ajax` call using GET semantics where the success callback puts the content in the element to which `load` is applied.  `post`, obviously, uses POST semantics and leaves it up to you to supply the callback, which can easily insert any new content delivered from the server.

Comment: thank you for the insights and the answer, This helped me put things into perspective and better understand how to use jquery tools.